# How to develop KF5 Plasmoids with Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator, kde-plasma

So far I have been developing plasmoids using Kate and commandline tools. This works fine but it would be nice to be able to use Qt designer to build the UI - and the biggest plus would be QML completion for the plasma components - these are especially under documented and best discovered by looking at the existing plasmoids.

So how do I get started developing plasmoids with Qt Creator? (if it's even possible?) - links for how to use CMake with Qt Creator are also welcome.

Comment: did you get any working solution ?

Comment: Not really - Qt Creator has got much better CMake support these days - but I ended up writing it with my own Kate + bash tools

Comment: yes I understand, I could not find any suitable ide for QML plasmoid .. I found very silly that kde develop do not support this kind of project out of the box ...

Comment: Yeah it's a shame

Answer (score 1):

Of course! You must start from here [Getting Started with QML2 & Plasma5](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/QML2/GettingStarted) and create **package structure**. Then you have to configure **CMakeLists.txt** and **metadata.desktop** as links teachs you and finally install it on your system with **plasmapkg2**. QtCreator it's just an IDE, almost must be done by you.

Also remember QtCreator could be configured to build your app automatically (*make install*).

Comment: Thanks I've refined my question. One problem is that the QML from the plasmoid specific components are hard to find any documentation for - and Qt Creator can code complete QML components automatically - which would help tremendously - so I was hoping you could get hold of e.g. template projects for plasmoids etc.

Comment: I understand you, there isn't many doc about QtQuick or QML. So I recommend you see examples on your system in this dir /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids. Here you can see all plasmoids you have installed, also you can retrieve code from them to learn. Good luck!